# How do I re-write this code in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
- (CGFloat)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSNumber* value = self.values[index];
return value.doubleValue;
}
```

I need to be able to set different values for different slices for a Pie Chart, but cannot seem to do so in Swift. It would greatly help if someone could re-write this code in Swift, and help me figure out how to set two slice values for two variables, votes and votes2.

Comment: This isn't a free code translation site. Make your own attempt first. If you have problems, update your question with your Swift code and explain the issues you are having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func pieChart(pieChart:XYPieChart!,index:Int!) ->CGFloat
 {
     let value:NSNumber = self.values[index] as NSNumber
     return value.doubleValue
 }
```

Comment: You are always welcome!

Comment: if it is working for you than you have to accept answer!